# G++ warning message Pycharm IDE

Tags: python, pycharm, pymc3

I was planning to do some examples with the Pymc3 package, however, I got these warnings regarding G++. I tried to look for solutions online, but, what I found is mainly for Linux or Mac and for windows it's for anaconda, but, not for Pycharm. What do these errors mean and can it be fixed in Pycharm IDE?

**Error Message:**

```
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not available, if using conda: `conda install m2w64-toolchain`
PyCharm\Projects\Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\theano\configdefaults.py:560: UserWarning: DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler.This is deprecated and with Theano 0.11 a c++ compiler will be mandatory
  warnings.warn("DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler."
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.
```

Comment: Why not install `g++` with `conda install m2w64-toolchain` ? it's in the error message.

Comment: "What do these errors mean" well, what part don't you understand, specifically? Do you know what g++ is? What Theano is? What BLAS is? Did you try the suggestion where it says "To remove this warning, ..."? Alternately did you try to install g++, as suggested at the top?